# What is the 'hidden' limit on file name length when using an ASP.NET FileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control, and when I select the file

> 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.txt'

, (which I can create in Windows with no problem), it is saying that it does not have a file when I postback.

It works fine for smaller file names. What's going on?

Comment: I am very curious as to why you would have a file with that name...

Comment: I'm testing some functionality that I have developed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could happen if you try to save the file in a folder on the server side (like a temp folder in c:\documents and settings\blabla...\temp) and exceed the MAX_PATH limit of 255 characters while on the client the file is located at the root and MAX_PATH is not reached.

Answer (score 3):

For windows it is 255 characters including the complete filepath.